# Create an Online Meeting Event in Microsoft Teams Using the Graph API

Tags: .net-6.0, msdn

We have a need to integrate Microsoft Teams with our application for scheduling online meetings. We are currently utilizing the API sample provided in the second example, and the process is successful. Microsoft Teams generates a meeting request, and attendees receive the corresponding email. However, we are encountering an issue where the online meeting link is not visible in the Microsoft Teams calendar event. Any assistance in resolving this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Refer to the following link for the API sample:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

Any assistance in resolving this matter would be greatly appreciated.